# Regex split strings with numeric char and subsequent values in Python

Tags: python, python-re

Having this list of values:

```
['Champiñón 200 g',
'Zapallo italiano Unid.',
'Bolsa de zanahoria 1 kg',
'Papa malla 2 Kg',
'Palta Hass granel',
'Limón malla 1 kg',
'Tomate granel',
'Brócoli 1 un.',
'Tomate  unid']
```

How could split this list using re.split() to obtain this form:

```
['Champiñón' , '200 g',
'Zapallo italiano' , 'Unid.',
'Bolsa de zanahoria' ,'1 kg',
'Papa malla' ,'2 Kg',
'Palta Hass granel',
'Limón malla' ,'1 kg',
'Tomate granel',
'Brócoli' ,'1 un.',
'Tomate'  ,'unid']
```

Comment: I don't get why 'unid' gets separated. no digit before it..

Comment: it's because unid is the same than 1 un

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import re

data = ['Champiñón 200 g',
'Zapallo italiano Unid.',
'Bolsa de zanahoria 1 kg',
'Papa malla 2 Kg',
'Palta Hass granel',
'Limón malla 1 kg',
'Tomate granel',
'Brócoli 1 un.',
'Tomate  unid']


splitted = []

for line in data:
    value, unit, *_ = *re.split(' ((\d|unid).*)', line, flags=re.IGNORECASE), ''

    splitted.append(value)

    if unit:
        splitted.append(unit)

print(splitted)
```

Comment: thanks! I was trying to figure out what was the pattern that I should use to split the values, your answer help me a lot

Comment: I've updated the regex based on @FMc 's solution. turned out there were some cases I've not accounted for

Answer (score 1):

In parsing situations, `split()` usually works best when you want to throw away the data you are splitting on. But you want to retain it, so you are probably better off using a capturing approach.

```
import re

orig_vals = [
    'Champiñón 200 g',
    'Zapallo italiano Unid.',
    'Bolsa de zanahoria 1 kg',
    'Papa malla 2 Kg',
    'Palta Hass granel',
    'Limón malla 1 kg',
    'Tomate granel',
    'Brócoli 1 un.',
    'Tomate  unid',
]

# We will capture the two parts of interest and
# only throw away a space in the middle. This regex is
# not super robust, but it does work correctly for the
# example data you have supplied.
rgx = re.compile('(.+) ((\d|unid).*)', re.IGNORECASE)

new_vals = []
for ov in orig_vals:
    m = rgx.search(ov)
    new_vals.extend([m.group(1).rstrip(), m.group(2)] if m else [ov])
```

And if you truly want to use splitting, you can write a more complex regex, using a lookahead -- to prevent consuming, and thus throwing away, of the text we are splitting on.

```
rgx2 = re.compile('(.+?) +(?=\d|unid)', re.IGNORECASE)

new_vals2 = [
    part
    for ov in orig_vals
    for part in rgx2.split(ov)
    if part
]
```

Comment: thanks! I was trying to figure out what was the pattern that I should use to split the values, your answer help me a lot

Comment: @cristobalvch There is a way to do it by splitting (see edited answer), but I don't recommend this approach, because it's more complex and harder to understand.